# TCP connection client IP address not used

Tags: python, macos, sockets

I am trying to receive a message sent from from a client via sockets. The following is the code I am using to receive that message

```
 def recieveData(serverPort):
      with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s 
            s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), serverPort)) #server bind to port               
            s.listen(5) #listen for connections
            while True:
                  c, addr = s.accept() #accept client connection
                  dataRecieved = c.recv(1024).decode() #get data sent from client
                  c.close() 
                  return dataRecieved
```

This works on my windows machine, but doesn't return anything on my mac. I also noticed on my mac that the variable `addr` is not used, but it is used on my windows computer.  Also the following

```
  print(socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())))
```

produces the following error on my mac, but it works on windows

> socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host`

Why is this? If I can get the warning that  says`addr` is not used, I think it will work.

Comment: The error is because the machine's name isn't in DNS. But you shouldn't need to bind to a specific IP. Just use an empty string to mean `INADDR_ANY`.

Comment: @Barmar If i replace the ip address argument in bind with `""`., I get `OSError: wildcard resolved to multiple address or my actual ip address`. Also, if i replace `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()` with my actual ip address, the same errors occur

Comment: Look at the first example at https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example it shows the use of an empty string for the host. I don't know why you get that error.